# Unable to unmarshal number into Go Value

Tags: go

I try to refrain from asking questions with simple answers but I can't seem to figure out what the issue is here... (Issue in title)

Relevant code:

```
match := new(Match)
if _, msgB, err = ws.ReadMessage(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}else {
    println(string(msgB))
    err = json.Unmarshal(msgB, match)

    if err != nil { panic(err) }
}


type Match struct {
    Teams [][]Char
    Map [][]Tile
    ID string //uuid
    Socket *websocket.Conn `json:'-'`
}
type Char struct {
    ID int
    HP int
    CT int
    Stats statList 
    X int
    Y int
    ACList Actions
}
type statList struct {
    Str int
    Vit int
    Int int
    Wis int
    Dex int
    Spd int
}
type Actions struct {
    Actions []Action
    TICKCT int
}
```

String to unmarshal (Formatted for visibility):

```
{
"Teams": [
    [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "HP": 10,
            "CT": 0,
            "Stats": [
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1
            ],
            "X": 0,
            "Y": 0,
            "ACList": {
                "Actions": [],
                "TICKCT": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "HP": 10,
            "CT": 0,
            "Stats": [
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1
            ],
            "X": 2,
            "Y": 2,
            "ACList": {
                "Actions": [],
                "TICKCT": 0
            }
        }
    ]
],
"Map": [
    [
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": 1
        },
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        },
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        },
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        },
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        },
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        },
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": 2
        }
    ]
],
"ID": "0b055e19-9b96-e492-b816-43297f12cc39"}
```

Error:

> 2014/03/28 12:11:41 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:56436: json: cannot
>   unmarshal number into Go value of type main.Char

Comment: Your json data doesn't match your data structures. Besides the error you see (you're getting a json Number where you expect a Char), I see that Stats is an array of numbers in json, but a struct in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a fixed version of the code ([playground](http://play.golang.org/p/SY6d6xzcmz)).  This seemed to be the main mistake:

```
type Char struct {
    ID     int
    HP     int
    CT     int
    Stats  []int // This was statList which won't work
    X      int
    Y      int
    ACList Actions
}
```

Also note the definition I made of `Tile` which allows numbers to be `nil`.

```
type Tile struct {
    Depth int
    Type  int
    Unit  *int
}
```

You didn't provide all the structures so I made some up - probably wrong! All together that is:

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Match struct {
    Teams [][]Char
    Map   [][]Tile
    ID    string //uuid
    //    Socket *websocket.Conn `json:'-'`
}

type Char struct {
    ID     int
    HP     int
    CT     int
    Stats  []int // This was statList which won't work
    X      int
    Y      int
    ACList Actions
}
type statList struct {
    Str int
    Vit int
    Int int
    Wis int
    Dex int
    Spd int
}
type Action string
type Actions struct {
    Actions []Action
    TICKCT  int
}

type Tile struct {
    Depth int
    Type  int
    Unit  *int
}

var data = `{
"Teams": [
    [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "HP": 10,
            "CT": 0,
            "Stats": [
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1
            ],
            "X": 0,
            "Y": 0,
            "ACList": {
                "Actions": [],
                "TICKCT": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "HP": 10,
            "CT": 0,
            "Stats": [
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1,
                1
            ],
            "X": 2,
            "Y": 2,
            "ACList": {
                "Actions": [],
                "TICKCT": 0
            }
        }
    ]
],
"Map": [
    [
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": 1
        },
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        },
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        },
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        },
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        },
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": null
        },
        {
            "Depth": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Unit": 2
        }
    ]
],
"ID": "0b055e19-9b96-e492-b816-43297f12cc39"}`

func main() {
    match := new(Match)
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), match)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("match = %#v\n", match)
}
```

Comment: Ah, I think it was the Tile struct, which has Unit as *Char (which I'll just have to change to *int as you suggested). Also the statlist mishap..